# Logging messages to pygtk.entry

Tags: python, python-2.7, logging, gtk, pygtk

I am currently developing gtk GUI for my python Application. I want to implement simple text entry which will contain all logging messages of application (something like console logging window in GUI). Unfortunately, I was only able to create logging handler that will print logging messages to a file or into console input:

```
def create_logger(logfile):
    logger = logging.getLogger("MyApp")

    file_logging = logging.FileHandler(logfile)
    file_logging.setLevel(logging.INFO)
    logger.addHandler(file_logging)

    console_logging = logging.StreamHandler()
    console_logging.setLevel(logging.INFO)
    logger.addHandler(console_logging)

return logger
```

Is there any way to set up logger handler that will log messages into Gtk Entry?

Comment: GtkEntry only displays a single line of text. You want GtkTextView instead.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want a simple solution, I'd recommend using a GtkLabel. The Label can show multi-line texts, and, if you want to highlight something, Label also accepts Markup (HTML-like tags).

A more complicated approach is using the GtkTextView widget. Basically you write to a GtkTextBuffer, which you previously connected to the GtkTextView to show it on-screen. With this widget you have a lot more possibilities, which you pay for with more complexity.

Here's an example. It's long because of the MainWindow creation necessary to make it runnable. Use the Label and packing properties to align the text where you'd like it.

```
import logging
import pygtk
import gtk

class MyHandler(logging.Handler):
    def __init__(self, label):
        logging.Handler.__init__(self)
        self.label = label

    def handle(self, rec):
        original = self.label.get_text()
        self.label.set_text(rec.msg + "\n" + original)

class MyLogger():
    def __init__(self, label):
        self.logger = logging.getLogger("Example")
        self.handler = MyHandler(label)
        #self.handler.setLevel(logging.INFO)
        self.logger.addHandler(self.handler)

    def warning(self, msg):
        self.logger.warning(msg)


class MainWindow(gtk.Window):
    def __init__(self):
        gtk.Window.__init__(self)
        self.set_size_request(200, 100)
        self.connect("delete-event", self.on_delete_event)

        self.loglabel = gtk.Label()
        self.add(self.loglabel)

        self.show_all()

    def run(self):
        gtk.mainloop()

    def on_delete_event(self, w, d):
        gtk.main_quit()


def main():
    mw = MainWindow()

    logger = MyLogger(mw.loglabel)
    logger.warning("This is a test message")
    logger.warning("This is another message")

    mw.run()
    return 0

if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()
```

The log entries are added somewhat artificially in the main program, else I'd have to add more widget. I've overridden the `warning` method to show how to do it. You can also override the `info`, and other handlers.

Note, as user4815162342 pointed out below, the method of using a label might not be optimal for very long logs. You can use a gtk.TextBuffer to do the same, or improve the above program by saving a copy of the text in the handler, adding the new message to it, and re-loading the Label's text.

Anyway, I suspect that the question was about how to send the log texts to somewhere else but a file or the terminal.

Comment: You should explain how to set up the logger handler in combination with a widget and not just describe some gtk widgets.

Comment: The OP almost certainly wants to write to a text view, erroneously called an "entry". The label example is dangerous because it has O(n^2) complexity due to having to construct larger and larger strings, and will therefore break the application as soon as it starts serious logging. It would be trivial to convert the example to use a `gtk.TextView`, which will both make sense algorithmically, and satisfy the requirements set forth by the OP. (Although it's true that a text view is more complicated than a label, in this particular example the implementation complexity would not change.)

Comment: @user4815162342 I wonder if the OP is still reading this thread. He posted the question 2 days ago.

Comment: That's hard to know, but improving an answer makes sense regardless of whether the OP is still there to read it; many people find responses via google searches years later. (I know I did much before I signed up to respond to SO answers.) If it makes it easier to parse my comment, feel free to read "The OP" as "someone in that situation".
P.S. In case it's not obvious, I'm not the downvoter.